# How to process two strings in one jq command?

Tags: text-processing, csv, jq

I am trying to process two strings in one `jq` command by mimicking the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529688/).

But I couldn't even get past simple tasks such as concatenate two strings (stored in bash variables `str1`, `str2`). I tried the following by adapting the SO answer:

```
jq -s -R '.[0] + .[1]' <(echo "$str1") <(echo "$str2")
```

But I get an error:

> jq: error (at /dev/fd/62:1): Cannot index string with number

I am new to jq.

*Can some one please explain how to fix the above jq usage?*

(This is with jq 1.6, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

**--Update--**

Just to clarify. 
What I have in mind is more complex. Basically, I need to parse the two strings (which are CSVs), and then combine the two parsed arrays of strings (roughly speaking). But I cannot get past getting the inputs.

As pointed out correctly in the comments, processing two raw strings may be better handled by other tools. And I can easily write a program too. But I just preferred jq's clean workflow.

Anyways, the real question is as posted above. But as a more specific example :

If I have two strings

```
str1='(a),(c),(b)'
str2='(a),(b)'
```

I wanted to write one `jq` command to parse the two arrays/sets and find out, e.g. their difference. So the expected output would be

```
(c)
```

I understand that `jq` can do all the sorting, set differences etc. (as the documentation and the linked SO question demonstrated), but I am not sure how to feed the two inputs into jq.

Comment: It's unclear what you want as output. If you run with `str1=hello` and `str2=world` and use just `jq -s -R .` you will see that you get a single string `hello\nworld\n` as output.

Comment: @Kusalananda What I have in mind is more complex. Basically, I need to parse the two strings (which are CSVs), and then combine the two parsed arrays of strings (roughly speaking). But I cannot get past getting the inputs.

Comment: It would be a benefit to your question if you could show us representative samples of data (and whether these are stored in one or several files), as well as whet the result should be after transforming it with `jq`.  As far as what you have said now, it seems that you're not actually working with JSON data, so `jq` may not be the correct tool to use.

Comment: @Kusalananda Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

I could try issuing the following command

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' <(comm -3 <(echo "${str1//,/$'\n'}" | sort) <(echo "${str2//,/$'\n'}" | sort))
```

Tests performed

```
$ str1='(a),(c),(b),(d)'
$ str2='(a),(b)'
$ sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' <(comm -3 <(echo "${str1//,/$'\n'}" | sort) <(echo "${str2//,/$'\n'}" | sort))
(c),(d)
```

The shell parameter substitution

```
echo "${str1//,/$'\n'}
```

replaces commas by newlines.

Since the `comm` command need the values sorted

```
echo "${str1//,/$'\n'}" | sort
```

To avoid having the newline of the last line replaced

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/'
```

NB. `-z` changes the delimiter to null characters (`\0`). This can come with its [limitations](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Limitations.html).